# how to access images from root directory on subdomain

Tags: html

I have `website.com/img` and have subdomain `sub.website.com` and would like to access images from the `img` folder on my subdomain but when I try the below the image isn't showing. Any help?

```
<img src="../../img/1.png">
<img src="../img/1.png">
<img src="/img/1.png">
```

Comment: You don't have that domain in any of your image tags.

Comment: I'm not too clued up on sub domains but a hosting package I had before  used to place sub domains in a folder at the root i.e. website.com/subdomain would be the real place the files were but the subdomain would represent it differently, it wasn't literally a folder behind the root. So you might find an answer if you can find out how your directory is laid out, do you have access to this? Alternatively you could just hard link it to the image you wanted i.e. <img src="http://website.com/img/image.png">

Comment: @haakym the subdomain is like the way you described it. website.com/subdomain

Comment: So is the html being run from the root or the subdomain?

Comment: Right, so it's like this: webpage is at website.com/subdomain/index.html and image folder is at subdomain too i.e. website.com/subdomain/img/1.png ?? If you get the paths of the web page and the img folder should be easier to solve it.

Comment: no the img folder is in root like website.com/img and yeah the the webpage is in subdomain website.com/subdomain/index.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="//website.com/img/1.png">
```

Your question is forces us to make a lot of assumptions. Are you using Apache? What does Apache's config say `sub.domain.com`'s serving directory is?

Comment: yep I am using apache. _ENV["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] /home/username/public_html/subdomain

Answer (score 0):

Use full url of the image file. So that, you can display in any pages...

```
<img src="http://www.url/images/image.jpg" />
```

I think, this will help you out.